# PHP internal hashCode Function

Tags: php

I am looking for the PHP equelent to JAVA's

```
 "SomeString".hashCode();
```

function. The hashCode i am looking for should be the same which is used for indexing Hashmaps in PHP. I Hope you can help me :)

EDIT:

Okay found the function i was searching for its written in C and is not available in PHP itself but thanks for your help !

```
ulong zend_inline_hash_func(char *arKey, uint nKeyLength)
{
        ulong $h = 5381;
        char *arEnd = arKey + nKeyLength;

        while (arKey < arEnd) {
                $h += ($h << 5);
                $h += (ulong) *arKey++;
        }
        return $h;
}
```

Comment: Why are all the answers below using 31? Isn't `$h += ($h << 5)` equivalent to `$h *= 33`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arkh and the github solution referenced by guiguoz are in the right direction, but both fail to take into account that PHP will upconvert the integer hash value to a double as soon as it exceeds 2^61. The java function, which is calculated using fixed hardware 32-bit signed values, involves 32-bit arithmetic overflow (intrinsic to the CPU) to keep the value as a 32-bit signed integer.

In PHP, you will need to manually perform that arithmetic overflow each time the $hash is updated:

```
function overflow32($v)
{
    $v = $v % 4294967296;
    if ($v > 2147483647) return $v - 4294967296;
    elseif ($v < -2147483648) return $v + 4294967296;
    else return $v;
}

function hashCode( $s )
{
    $h = 0;
    $len = strlen($s);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        $h = overflow32(31 * $h + ord($s[$i]));
    }

    return $h;
}
```

(edit: corrected %v typo)

Comment: The overflow32 method is wrong (%v instead of $v, and it divides by 0 on a 32bit machine). Instead, the $h = line should read:`$h = (int)(31 * $h + ord($s[$i])) & 0xffffffff;`

Comment: @xryl669, your line will return wrong on `hashCode("153193cc3139f12e")`. it returns 3369976574 instead of -924990722.

Comment: This is still not applicable for 32-bit systems.

Comment: Is it possible to replace overflow32() with `& 0x7FFFFFFF`? Or would there be other issues?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such method available in php. So you will have to implement the correct method.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29#The_java.lang.String_hash_function) gives the algorithm used by Java.lang.hashCode which is used by strings I think, so here is a quick php version of it:

```
<?php
function getStringHashCode($string){
  $hash = 0;
  $stringLength = strlen($string);
  for($i = 0; $i < $stringLength; $i++){
    $hash = 31 * $hash + $string[$i];
  }
  return $hash;
}
```

Comment: thx for this code but i need EXACTLY the same used internal for building hashmaps.

Comment: This function is wrong, https://gist.github.com/andreyknupp/5061911 has a correct implementation, but it still yields different hashes if the String has spaces on it.

Answer (score 1):

[spl_object_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) is probably the closest to what you want, but despite the name it does not really return a hash of the passed in value, merely an internal unique identifier. I don't know if it's the hash actually used under the hood for arrays etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents for implementing Java's hashCode in PHP:

```
/**
 * Simulates java hashCode function
 * hash a string to 32 bit
 * @param str the string to hash
 * @return hashed 32 bit integer
 */
function hashCode($str) {
    $str = (string)$str;
    $hash = 0;
    $len = strlen($str);
    if ($len == 0 )
        return $hash;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $h = $hash << 5;
        $h -= $hash;
        $h += ord($str[$i]);
        $hash = $h;
        $hash &= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
    return $hash;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not equal, but very fast:

```
function hashCode32Signed($str)
{
    return unpack('l', hash('crc32', $str, true))[1];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

a utf-8 version with emoji support

```
function str_hashcode($s){
    $hash = 0;
    $len = mb_strlen($s, 'UTF-8');
    if($len == 0 )
        return $hash;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        $c = mb_substr($s, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
        $cc = unpack('V', iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4LE', $c))[1];
        $hash = (($hash << 5) - $hash) + $cc;
        $hash &= $hash; // 16bit > 32bit
    }
    return $hash;
}
```

Comment: This function returns the same hash for 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-gggg-hhhh-iiii-jjjj-kkkk-11111' as 'aaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeee-ffff-gggg-hhhh-iiii-jjjj-kkkk-22222'. jshouchin's accepted answer also supports emoji's.