# What is the equivalent of .Net's GetHashCode() in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am new to PHP scripting. I developed a VB.net application in which I am using `GetHashCode()` function for generating activation key. Now I want to generate activation key using PHP.

Can anyone help me to get the equivalent PHP function? Below I have written the example of VB.Net.

```
Dim MyString As String = "hello"
MsgBox(MyString.GetHashCode)
```

Output:

> -695839

Comment: Check out this related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804875/php-internal-hashcode-function

Comment: The implementation of GetHashCode() is undefined in .net and can and does change between versions, use a specified hash function like SHA256

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx - `GetHashCode` on the .Net side "Consumers of GetHashCode cannot rely upon it being stable over time or across appdomains"

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099998/hash-quality-and-stability-of-string-gethashcode-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that with `String.GetHashCode`.

You can not persist result of `String.GetHashCode` as it may/will change between launches of the same program - so even if there is "equivalent" method in PHP you can't use really compare they results.

You need to use some custom code both sides agree on.

I.e. use SHA256 to compute hash of the string - there are many samples how to compute hash in either language i.e. [hmac_sha256 in php and c# differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699041/hmac-sha256-in-php-and-c-sharp-differ) covers both. If writing code yourself make sure to understand how to encode strings (i.e. UTF8) and result (i.e. Hex or Base64).